# Pytorch Text classification example - error while training, some issues with indexing

Tags: python, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to train a model on text classification. Every time I run the training block, I run into some or other index related key error. I have reset the index many times, try to drop the columns but it didnt help. Below is the piece of code ( please ignore the lines after the error message, they are just random check to see if the index value is present

I try to reset the index, dropped the secondary index adverty created and try to perform train test split on the clean dataset. Still the key error persist.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import spacy
# Define a custom dataset class
class TicketDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, labels, vocab):
        self.data = data
        self.labels = labels
        self.vocab = vocab

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        try:
            text = self.data[idx]
            label = self.labels[idx]
            
            # Convert text to numerical representation
            text_ids = [self.vocab.get(word, 0) for word in text.split()]
            
            # Pad sequences to a fixed length
            max_len = 191
            text_ids = text_ids[:max_len] + [0] * (max_len - len(text_ids))
            
            return torch.tensor(text_ids), torch.tensor(label)
        except KeyError as e:
            if e.args[0] == 3247:  # Check for specific key (3247)
                print(f"Error: Key {e.args[0]} not found in data or labels.")
                return None, None  # Handle the error gracefully
            else:
                raise e  # Re-raise other KeyError exceptions
# Define the neural network model
class TextClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes):
        super(TextClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, num_classes)

    def forward(self, text_ids):
        # Embed text tokens
        embedded = self.embedding(text_ids)

        # Pass through LSTM
        _, (hidden, _) = self.lstm(embedded.unsqueeze(0))

        # Extract final hidden state
        output = hidden.squeeze(0)

        # Apply linear layer and softmax
        logits = self.fc(output)
        probs = F.softmax(logits, dim=1)
        return probs
nn_data = pd.read_csv('Clean_data_nn.csv')
nn_data.drop(columns=['Unnamed: 0'], inplace=True)
nn_data['Issue_Description'] = nn_data['Issue_Description'].str.replace('\s{2,}', ' ', regex=True)
nn_data = nn_data[['Issue_Description','Category']]

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
nn_data['Issue_Description'] = nn_data['Issue_Description'].astype(str)
values_to_map = nn_data['Category'].unique()
label_mapping = {category : idx for idx,category in enumerate(values_to_map)}
nn_data['Category'] = nn_data['Category'].map(label_mapping)
label_mapping
{'batch': 0,
 'functional': 1,
 'ad hoc': 2,
 'data reports': 3,
 'data setup issue': 4,
 'working as expected': 5,
 'performance': 6,
 'access requests or uar': 7,
 'incorrect assignment': 8}
nn_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
nn_data.iloc[3222]
Issue_Description    panel broker file
Category                             3
Name: 3222, dtype: object
text = ''
vocab = {}
text = ' '.join(nn_data['Issue_Description'])
# Process the text with spaCy
doc = nlp(text)
# Extract unique words (lemmas) from the processed text
vocab = {token.lemma_: idx for idx, token in enumerate(doc)}
# Text preprocessing (modify this based on your needs)
text_length = max(len(text.split()) for text in nn_data['Issue_Description'])
text_length
191
# Load your data (replace with your actual loading logic)
data = nn_data['Issue_Description']  # Replace with your data
labels = nn_data['Category']  # Replace with your labels
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# Prepare datasets
train_data, val_data, train_labels, val_labels = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=0.2)
train_dataset = TicketDataset(train_data, train_labels, vocab)
val_dataset = TicketDataset(val_data, val_labels, vocab)
train_dataset
<__main__.TicketDataset at 0x27f3df68850>
# Define hyperparameters
vocab_size = len(vocab)
embedding_dim = 128
hidden_dim = 64
num_classes = 9
batch_size = 32
learning_rate = 0.001
epochs = 10
# Create dataloaders
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)
# Create the model and optimizer
model = TextClassifier(vocab_size, embedding_dim, hidden_dim, num_classes)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

# Define the loss function (consider using weighted cross-entropy for imbalanced data)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
# Training loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    model.train()
    for i, (text_ids, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        print(i, text_ids, labels)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(text_ids)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        if i % 100 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}/{epochs}, Step: {i+1}/{len(train_loader)}, Loss: {loss.item():.4f}")`
`Error Message When running the training block: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3791, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3790 try:
-> 3791     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3792 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 9

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[213], line 4
      2 for epoch in range(epochs):
      3     model.train()
----> 4     for i, (text_ids, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
      5         print(i, text_ids, labels)
      6         optimizer.zero_grad()

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:631, in _BaseDataLoaderIter.__next__(self)
    628 if self._sampler_iter is None:
    629     # TODO(https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/76750)
    630     self._reset()  # type: ignore[call-arg]
--> 631 data = self._next_data()
    632 self._num_yielded += 1
    633 if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \
    634         self._IterableDataset_len_called is not None and \
    635         self._num_yielded > self._IterableDataset_len_called:

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py:675, in _SingleProcessDataLoaderIter._next_data(self)
    673 def _next_data(self):
    674     index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 675     data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    676     if self._pin_memory:
    677         data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data, self._pin_memory_device)

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:51, in _MapDatasetFetcher.fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     49         data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50     else:
---> 51         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     52 else:
     53     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py:51, in <listcomp>(.0)
     49         data = self.dataset.__getitems__(possibly_batched_index)
     50     else:
---> 51         data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     52 else:
     53     data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

Cell In[192], line 29, in TicketDataset.__getitem__(self, idx)
     27     return None, None  # Handle the error gracefully
     28 else:
---> 29     raise e

Cell In[192], line 13, in TicketDataset.__getitem__(self, idx)
     11 def __getitem__(self, idx):
     12     try:
---> 13         text = self.data[idx]
     14         label = self.labels[idx]
     16         # Convert text to numerical representation

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1040, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
   1037     return self._values[key]
   1039 elif key_is_scalar:
-> 1040     return self._get_value(key)
   1042 # Convert generator to list before going through hashable part
   1043 # (We will iterate through the generator there to check for slices)
   1044 if is_iterator(key):

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py:1156, in Series._get_value(self, label, takeable)
   1153     return self._values[label]
   1155 # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
-> 1156 loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
   1158 if is_integer(loc):
   1159     return self._values[loc]

File ~\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3798, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3793     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3794         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3795         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3796     ):
   3797         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3798     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3799 except TypeError:
   3800     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3801     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3802     #  the TypeError.
   3803     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 9
len(train_loader)
147`
`
```